# codesign wants me to sign my data files as well?

Tags: xcode, macos, sign, codesign, mach-o

I have an OSX application, and in the bundle's `MacOS` directory, I have an executable and a bunch of dylibs. The executable is, of course, pointed to by the `Info.plist`'s `CFBundleExecutable` entry. When I try to sign it, `codesign` complains (as of 10.9) that my dylibs aren't signed, which makes sense. So I sign all of the dylibs, which I would think would let me sign the main executable now.

The problem is that I actually have a couple of data files in my `MacOS` dir, as well. The application is a cross-platform Qt application and the data files are localizations files that are found with respect to the main executable. `codesign` complains that it doesn't want to sign my main executable until the data files are signed.

Is this just a fundamentally wrong thing to be doing - putting anything that isn't mach-o into `MacOS`? Is signing those data files even a reasonable thing to do - ie like a .cat file on Windows? Clearly I wouldn't want `codesign` haphazardly slapping a digest hash on to the end of my data files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes those data files should go into the `Resources` folder.

From the [*Bundle Programming Guide*](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/corefoundation/conceptual/cfbundles/BundleTypes/BundleTypes.html)

> **MacOS** (Required)
>
> Contains the application’s standalone executable code. Typically, this directory contains only one binary file with
>   your application’s main entry point and statically linked code.
>   However, you may put other standalone executables (such as
>   command-line tools) in this directory as well.
>
> **Resources**
>
> Contains all of the application’s resource files. This contents of this directory are further organized to distinguish
>   between localized and nonlocalized resources. For more information
>   about the structure of this directory, see “[The Resources Directory](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/corefoundation/conceptual/cfbundles/BundleTypes/BundleTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001119-110730)”

Codesigning the data files won't change them; they are simply recorded in the `_CodeSignature/CodeResources` file.